# How can I display a message in the web app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display messages, such as an error message, to the user When press the button. But none of the snackbar and AlertDialog are displayed on the web app.

Further and for more explanation for AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog(  
            title: Text('myMessageShow'), 
           ),
```

and for snackbar:

```
SnackBar(
           content: Text('myMessageShow'),
        ),
```

but they didn't work.

What suggestions and ways do you have to display the message?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. If neither AlertDialogues nor snackbar are showing up, maybe you're handling them wrong. I suggest you to read more carefully the documentation and provide more context on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you saw it on the screen because you used it wrong. Use as follows.

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      title: Text('myMessageShow'),
      ));
```